# SimpleAdapter duplicating items

Tags: android, listactivity, simpleadapter

I am using `SimpleAdapter` for displaying a `ListView`, but whenever I press the back button, and open the activity (which shows the list) again, the entries of the list become double.

If I do it again, array values again concatenates with the items of the list.

List variable of array is declared as

```
 private static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

my code in `onCreate()` of `List.java`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.list);



    HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp.put("first","Strength");
    temp.put("second", strength);
    list.add(temp);


    HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp1.put("first","what");
    temp1.put("second", "??");
    list.add(temp1);


    HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp2.put("first","Time");
    temp2.put("second", "time");
    list.add(temp2);


    HashMap<String,String> temp3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp3.put("first","Repeat");
    temp3.put("second", "everyday");
    list.add(temp3);




    setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.row_view, new String [] {"first","second"}, new int [] {R.id.rowTextView1, R.id.rowTextView2} ));
```

Comment: what is object "list" you haven't declared it at all in this code, please post your full code.

Comment: Marking the question as '*urgent*' is not going to help! What have you tried?

Comment: try list.clear() before all of this code?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish, but there is almost surely a better way then using an ArrayList of HashMaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an if statement to check to see if there is anything already in list or not, like this:

```
if(list.size() == 0){

HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
temp.put("first","Strength");
temp.put("second", strength);
list.add(temp);


HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
temp1.put("first","what");
temp1.put("second", "??");
list.add(temp1);


HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
temp2.put("first","Time");
temp2.put("second", "time");
list.add(temp2);


HashMap<String,String> temp3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
temp3.put("first","Repeat");
temp3.put("second", "everyday");
list.add(temp3);
}
```

Comment: thankssss alotttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt dude, may u live long